# How to get current CPU/Memory/WiFi traffic in FireFox OS App?

Tags: linux, firefox-os

I want to use `HTML5`/`CSS`/`Javascript` code to get CPU / Memory / WiFi traffic data, but I cannot find how to use linux shell command in HTML:

`top`

`/proc/meminfo`

`/sys/class/net/wlan0/statistics/rx_bytes`

Also I cannot find in webAPI.

Is it possible to get information in FFOS App ?

Comment: It won't be possible unless there is a webapi for it.

Comment: But I find Setting -> Developer -> Develper HUD can show App Memory
http://imgur.com/b05l9TL
Is it not using Javascript to implement ?

Answer (score 0):

Only certified (internal) apps can access the local file system. The built-in Firefox OS Settings app uses JS code to read local files, via the XMLHttpRequest() API. Unfortunately no regular app can do that. You can use the XMLHttpRequest() API to access HTTP data, but when you try to do that on a local file, the call will fail.